# Laravel PHP function Route::resource to create non-english API

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I have a web app dealing with contracts and clients essentially. I actually created my routes like following (do not be surprised if the routes are not in English, my application works with French records) :

```
Route::get('/client', 'ClientController@index');
Route::get('/client/{id}', 'ClientController@getById')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
Route::get('/client/{search}', 'ClientController@getByText')->where('search', '[a-z_.-\s]+');
Route::get('/client/creer'); // Form to create a new client
Route::post('/client/', 'ClientController@new');
// And so on ...
```

You will notice the comments, because there is so much routes that I just cannot put them all here. And that why I am wondering...

**Question**

Can I use this command instead :

```
Route::resource('client', 'ClientController');
```

But with non-english routes names ? Like instead of having `client/create` I would autmatically have `client/creer` ('creer' is the French traduction of 'create').

**Alternative Question**

If Laravel does not implement this kind of option, can I have a look at the file and update it myself ? If yes, where may I found this method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rename resource routes with:

```
Route::resource('client', 'ClientController', [
    'names' => [
        'create' => 'client.creer'
    ]
]);
```

Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers